# c# winform above chrome in kiosk mode

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome

I'm having trouble getting a winform to appear above chrome in kiosk mode. 
My goal is to have a transparent window display certain system information on top of all other windows. I have set `this.TopMost = true` and have even added the script:

```
private void keepWindowOnTop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!this.TopMost || !this.TopLevel)
            {
                this.TopMost = true;
                this.TopLevel = true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Still, when my winform launches chrome kiosk is on top.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I need the transparent window to always be in the foreground even when other windows are selected (clicked). This feature works fine when running from Visual Studios, but after the application is installed on a separate system it breaks.

Could it be because I'm importing the .dll at run time? Does that have any effect on `TopLevel`?

cheers

Comment: Is Chrome also setting topmost? If multiple windows have the topmost flag set, their display order determines which one shows on top of the other(s). You may have to play around with the topmost flag to make this work.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep`.  Your code will not work at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! There's no GUI to block and the function is run at the end. So `Thread.Sleep` should have no effect right? See my edit for clarification.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of making a Chrome plugin? If you always need your stuff on top of Chrome, you may be better of launching it from inside Chrome. Coordinating multiple processes is very fragile unless both sides actively cooperate. If you need nothing but topmost, this may work out but applications like this typically evolve over time toward tighter integration.

Comment: Why do you have `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: I put that method in there to set TopLevel to true every second. It was just something I tried out and is not critical to the code. The winform functions just fine without it. So, consider it removed.

Comment: _"So Thread.Sleep should have no effect right? "_ - then why use it?